# in Rails how do I change what styles are imported based on the URL

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, materialize, material-design-lite

In Rails 4.2 I want to transition from using "Materialize" to style the views to using "Material Design Lite"

The Materialize styles require me to have `@import 'materialize';` in `application.scss` and the MDL styles require me to have `@import 'material';` in the same file.

My problem is that when I import the Materialize styles it breaks the MDL ones. If I remove the Materialize import statement the MDL styles work, but any page that I haven't transitioned to MDL styles is then completely unstyled.

It's too big an app to make the transition to MDL in one go. I want to have some pages styled with MDL while others are styled with Materialize during the transition process.

Is there any way of of making the import statement in `application.scss` conditional on which page the user is viewing?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the materialize import statement from `application.scss` then I set up conditionals inside `views/layouts/application.html.erb` which sets a flag based on the current path. If the current path is one that has been transitioned to MDL then it sets the `mdl` flag to be true. (Currently only the login page is transitioned.)

```
<%
  if current_page?(login_path)
    mdl = true
  else
    mdl = false
  end
%>
```

Then in the page head I import the Materialize css and js through CDN unless the page is using MDL

```
<% unless mdl %>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS and JS for Materialize -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<% end %>
```

I think the consequence of this would be that Materialize is no longer in the asset pipeline, which may slow things down a little until the transition is done.

I also now have two partials for the header bar and I render the correct one based on the `mdl` flag.